# Supabase login get user session and profile at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, supabase

Is there a way to get the user session and profile at the same time? The way I did it would be get the user session first after login then fetch the user profile using the id.

```
  const [authsession, setSession] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const userSession = supabase.auth.session();
    setSession(userSession);
    if (userSession) {
      getProfile(userSession.user.id);
    } else {
      setSession((s) => ({ ...s, profile: null }));
    }
    supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((_event, session) => {
      setSession(session);

      if (session) {
        getProfile(session.user.id);
      } else {
        setSession((s) => ({ ...s, profile: null }));
      }
    });
  }, []);
  const getProfile = async (id) => {
    setLoading(true);
    setError(false);
    try {
      const { data } = await supabase
        .from("profiles")
        .select("*")
        .eq("id", id)
        .single();
      setSession((s) => ({ ...s, profile: data }));
    } catch (error) {
      setError(true);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Hi! Did you find a solution to this? I'm struggling with the same thing, and the only answer here doesn't work for me (copying profile data into auth.users table doesn't seem like a good idea)

Answer (score 0):

The `session.user` object contains a property called `user_metadata` - this property contains the data which is present in the `raw_user_meta_data` column of the of `auth.users` table.

Hence, you can setup a DB trigger on your custom user profile table which copies the data from that table to the `raw_user_meta_data` column of the of `auth.users` table in JSON format anytime the data in the user profile table changes (i.e. you will need the trigger to be run on INSERT/UPDATE and probably DELETE statements). This way the profile data will be automatically delivered to the client with the sign-in or token refresh events.

IMPORTANT: This approach has potential drawbacks:

- this data will also be part of the JWT sent to the user. This might be a problem because the JWT is NOT easy to revoke BEFORE its expiration time and you might end up in a situation where a JWT which expires in 1 hour (and will be refreshed in 1 hour) still contains profile data which has already been updated on the server. The implications of this really depends on what you put in your profile data and how you use it in the client and/or the backend;
- since this data is in the JWT, the data will be re-sent to the client with each refresh of the session (which is every 1 hour by default). So, (a) if the profile data is big, you would be sending this large piece of data on every token refresh even if it has NOT changed and (b) if the data changes often and you need to ensure that the client is up to date in (near) real time you will need to increase the token refresh rate;

Answer (score 0):

*(In support of [@chipilov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72324990), but too long for a comment.)*

#### Solution

When you get the user session at login time, Supabase will additionally return the JSON stored in `auth.users.raw_user_meta_data`. So, save the profile info there at signup time with [`supabase.auth.signUp()`](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-signup) or later with [`supabase.auth.updateUser()`](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-updateuser), you are all set.

#### Should you really store profile data in `auth.users`?

People seem to freak out a bit at the prospect of writing into `auth.users`, probably fearing that they might mess with Supabase internals. However, `raw_user_meta_data` is *meant* for this purpose: Supabase itself does not save anything into that column, only the additional user metadata that you may provide at signup or when updating a user.

Supabase maintainers do not recommend to write with own server-side routines to `auth.users` ([source](https://github.com/supabase/supabase/discussions/6363#discussioncomment-2527443)). But we don't do that here, relying only on the Supabase-provided functions [`supabase.auth.signUp()`](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-signup) and [`supabase.auth.updateUser()`](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-updateuser).

In the Supabase docs, they even provide an example where this "additional user metadata" is used for profile information:

```
const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signUp(
  {
    email: 'example@email.com',
    password: 'example-password',
    options: {
      data: {
        first_name: 'John',
        age: 27,
      }
    }
  }
)
```

*(Source: [Supabase Documentation: JavaScript [Client Library] v2.0: AUTH: Create a new user](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-signup), example "Sign up with additional user metadata")*

#### How to access this profile data server-side?

The OP uses a table `public.profiles` to maintain profile information. For additional profile information that you generate and write to server-side, this is the recommended practice. Such a table is also recommended to make user data from `auth.users` accessible through the API:

> GaryAustin1 (Supabase maintainer): "You could use the user meta data [field to store your additional metadata] and update it server side. The recommendation though normally is to have your own copy of key user info from the `auth.users` table […] [in] your own user table. This table is updated with a trigger function on `auth.users` inserts/updates/deletes." ([source](https://github.com/supabase/supabase/discussions/6363#discussioncomment-2527443))

Instead of a set of trigger functions, you may also **opt for a VIEW** with `SECURITY definer` privileges to make `auth.users` data available in the `public` schema and thus via the API. Compared to triggers, it does not introduce redundancy, and I also think it's simpler. Such a view can also include your `auth.users.raw_user_meta_data` JSON split nicely into columns, as explored in [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/151838). **For security**, be sure to include row access filtering via the `WHERE` clause of this view ([instructions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/301113)), because VIEWs cannot have their own row-level security (RLS) policies.

#### How to modify this profile data server-side?

**Your own user table** in the `public` schema can be used to store that additional profile data. It would be connected to `auth.users` with a foreign key relation. In the VIEW proposed above, you can then include both data from this own table and columns from `auth.users`.

Of course, user information from your own table will then not be returned automatically on login. If you cannot live with that, then I propose to **alternatively use `auth.users.raw_user_meta_data`** to save your additional metadata. I know [I disagree with a Supabase maintainer](https://github.com/supabase/supabase/discussions/6363#discussioncomment-2527443) here, but really, you're not messing with Supabase internals, just writing into a field that nothing in Supabase depends on.

You would use PostgreSQL functions (with `SECURITY definer` set) to provide access to specific JSON properties of `auth.users.raw_user_meta_data` from within the `public` schema. These functions can even be exposed to the API automatically ([see](https://dev.to/davepar/going-serverless-with-supabase-103h)).

If however you also need to prevent write access by users to some of your user metadata, then the own table solution from above is usually better. You *could* use triggers on `auth.users.raw_user_meta_data`, but it seems rather complex.